# Error: Sending 'float[3]' to parameter of incompatible type 'float'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have a typedef struct such as the following:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex;
```

I want to iterate through data for Position, Color, and TexCoord:

```
+ (void)arrayConverter: (Vertex *) v
{

    // Turn typeDef struct into seperate arrays
    NSMutableArray *position   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int p=0; p<(sizeof(v->Position)/sizeof(v)); p++) {
        [position addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:v[p].Position]]; // Error: Sending 'float[3]' to parameter of incompatible type 'float'
    }
}
```

Data that is passed in:

```
Vertex Square_Vertices[] = {
    // Front
    {{0.5, -0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-0.5, -0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    // Back
    {{0.5, 0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-0.5, -0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{0.5, -0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    // Left
    {{-0.5, -0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-0.5, -0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    // Right
    {{0.5, -0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{0.5, 0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{0.5, -0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    // Top
    {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{0.5, 0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    // Bottom
    {{0.5, -0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{0.5, -0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-0.5, -0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-0.5, -0.5, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}}
};
```

How can I iterate through the data and add to my NSMutableArray without getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over all elements of `v->Position` for a single vertex, it should be

```
for (int p=0; p<(sizeof(v->Position)/sizeof(v->Position[0])); p++) {
    [position addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:v->Position[p]]];
}
```

**UPDATE:** For an array of vertices, your method could look like this:

```
+ (void)arrayConverter: (Vertex *)vertices count:(NSUInteger)count
{
    NSMutableArray *position   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Vertex *v = vertices;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int p=0; p<(sizeof(v->Position)/sizeof(v->Position[0])); p++) {
            [position addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:v->Position[p]]];
        }
        v++;
    }
}
```

If

```
Vertex Square_Vertices[] = { ... }
```

is an array of vertices, you would call the method

```
[YourClass arrayConverter:Square_Vertices count:(sizeof(Square_Vertices)/sizeof(Square_Vertices[0]))];
```

Comment: When I do this I do not get all of the data I am passing in.

Comment: @user1585646: Do you want to add the positions of one vertex or of an array of vertices? - Perhaps show how the method is called.

Comment: @user1585646: Then you have to pass the number of vertices to the method, and loop over all vertices ...

Comment: I pass the number of vertices but how do I loop over all vertices correctly. See edit for data I am trying to pass in.

Comment: @user1585646: No, your method gets only the address of one vertex, not the number of vertices. See updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @user1585646: Note that if you pass an *array* to a function, it "decays" to a pointer, so the called function cannot determine how many array array elements there are.